# Does purchasing IAP from abroad increase the risk of getting my account disabled?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

So I'm outside USA , and I want to buy the kingdom rush frontiers IAP. Can I do this safely or do I risk getting my account disabled because i use to buy IAP from USA Apple ID outside USA ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

As long as your account is registered in U.S., and has an active U.S. credit card linked to it, you can make purchase wherever and whenever you want with that account.

I should add though, you should have your account transferred to the country you live. If you're traveling, it's fine.

Comment: if i use Gift card ? it is still safe ?

Comment: Yes. It will still be safe.

Comment: how can i transfered my account ? does it will transfer all my app purchased history too ?

Comment: I would suggest you contact iTunes support directly about this. The last time I checked if a purchased item is also on the destination store, it will be transferred. But again, don't take my word for it, contact iTunes support directly.